# Ceiling fan install fail! I have 12 wires in 6 different colors. Please help!

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Ok so old fan was removed about a year ago.  Dad wired new few but never got it totally right.  The switch worked and ran the fan but the lights never worked at all.  No lights was driving me crazy so my husband decided to fix it.  Now we have 2 Gray, 3 white, 1 black, 1 red,  1 green, 1 bare sticking out of ceiling; 1 blue, 1 white, 1 black sticking outta fan, no power at all to bedroom and the bathroom and living room are also out and for good measure the furnace  seems to have joined the strike as well because we have no heat and it's well below freezing outside.  Please help!  To say there is no money for an electrician is an understatement!  I mean I could not call 1 if I wanted to cuz can't pay with what we Flat don't have.  I know my ignorance in this department makes me less than ideal pupil and it could be a risky handicap but please I usually can figure things out quickly and I'm aware the smart play is call someone but I can't so please does anyone have any advice for us?  I shut the power off at the breaker box already I will try to attach pics[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box?

Comment: Also, do you have some way of identifying which is the incoming "hot" feed, and which wires have continuity to each other?

Comment: I can run borrow a tester but not sure how to test continuity to each other.  Sorry.  If you give me broad strokes I will figure it out though.   Pic of switch box on way

Comment: Does the light switch control multiple lights other than at just the fan?

Answer (score 1):

The "dark gray"s are actually blacks.   Gray is also a color used in wiring, and it has a very different meaning from black.  Yours is not that.

Note that the wires aren't just random, they are grouped in *cables* entering the box.

Locate the cable with a red wire.  Note that it also has a white and black.   This is the run down to the switch.  Cap each of these wires individually with orange or yellow wire nuts, tape the nuts down so they don't easily fall off, and pull the wires out of the way.  You will not be using them today.

What remains should be 2 black and 2 white. One white/black pair comes from supply.  The other goes to your downline loads like the furnace.  Nut the black to the black, and white to the white.

Turn the power back on.  Everything *else* should work now.

Then call in a professional for the finish... or school up by getting a book on household electrical at the library, and reading most of it.  Not skimming or cherry picking.  Reading.

Comment: It looks like the 12/3 has both a hot and a switched in it...

Comment: I will try everything suggested and let you know how it works.  Thank you guys very much I know it's late and almost Christmas.  I hope I didn't keep you from family but you sure are saving me and mine! Thank you!

Comment: ThreePhaseEel what does it mean if 12/3 has both hot and switched?       I paired the wires as it said to and no luck when turned power back on.   All rooms still dead

Comment: @Harper I wonder if the black from the switch is the source hot, and the other two black wires both go downstream; it would explain why nothing works afterward.

Comment: @RobertNubel yes, I think you are right,  in which case all blacks should be joined to all whites, reds capped off.